# "booting in insecure mode" message after disabling secure boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I needed to disable secure boot, because my wireless adapter was not working. I disabled it by typing `sudo mokutil --disable-validation` into the terminal. Entering all of the passwords needed. Rebooting and going into the MOK manager. Then disabling secure boot. That fixed my problem. But now every time I boot up my computer I get a message saying "Booting in insecure mode" before the grub menu shows up. The message adds a few seconds to my boot time and also makes the grub show up in a resolution smaller than before. Is there a way to make this message stop appearing?

Comment: "Is there a way to make this message stop appearing?" Yes, enable secure boot. "I needed to disable secure boot, because my wireless adapter was not working"  You can only fix that by finding a signed driver. I doubt there are any other options. I would advice to include info on the wireless. A lot do have signed drivers.

Comment: @Rinzwind I tried re-enabling secure boot using `sudo mokutil --disable-validation`, but I couldn't find an option for enabling secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following command to re-enable Secure Boot validation, which will eventually not show the text "booting in insecure mode".

```console
$ sudo mokutil --enable-validation
```

Sources - 
https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot

You can check the status of Secure Boot by -

```console
$ mokutil --sb-state
```

For you, the output might be -

```
SecureBoot enabled
SecureBoot validation is disabled in shim
```